# What changes are needed for HTTPrequest to work on Device instead of Emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httprequest

I have been working on an app that sends a JSON object using a PUT request and I have this successfully working and saving the data on my Oracle Database. However, this is through using the emulator on Android Studio and using my computer's IP address in the URL.

I have now tried to send the request from my android device and instead of my computer's IP address I have used the localhost which was advised. Although this did not work as expected and I received no response or the database did not save the record.

What differences are needed when sending a request on an android device instead of an Android emulator??

Using AsyncTask also.. can show code if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use ``localhost``? That points to the android device itself.

Comment: What would be used then? @f1sh ??

Comment: You should now use your computers IP address.

Comment: even though my device isn't connected to my computer?? I am sending over my company network

Comment: As long as your computer and your device are both on that network, yes.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: it is not triggering a response from my RESTapi or nothing

Comment: Try the url in a browser on your device.